# Changing hash_key with Terraform causes Table already exists error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.14.7

I have a DynamoDB table created with this Terraform:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "materials_table" {
  name              = "materials"
  hash_key          = "MATERIAL"
  billing_mode      = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity     = 5
  write_capacity    = 5
  
  attribute {
    name = "MATERIAL"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

The table was successfully populated (with 4 records, as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382143/lambda-only-inserts-4-records-but-iterates-248-times/66382584#66382584)) but in order to solve the problem (in that post) I have added a field `PK` and set that as the `hash_key` field, with this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "materials_table" {
  name              = "materials"
  hash_key          = "PK"
  billing_mode      = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity     = 5
  write_capacity    = 5
  
  attribute {
    name = "PK"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

This has caused the following error, when running `terraform apply`:

```
Error: error creating DynamoDB Table: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: materials
```

What do I need to do in the `.tf` to get the change accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing some of the attributes in DynamoDB is not permitted, for example, changing Partition key, adding a Local Secondary Index, etc.

When such changes occur, it will need to replace the resource and to replace, it will try to delete and re-create the resource. During this process, if table already exists, it will fail.

Only option is to delete the stack or manually delete the DynamoDB Table and let template create it again. Or Renaming the table.

[Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table) says it will force new resource

> hash_key - (Required, Forces new resource) The attribute to use as the
> hash (partition) key.

Comment: I'm using Terraform, not CloudFormation.

Comment: I was expecting the table to be deleted, but the error implies this is not being attempted.

Comment: I think, it will first try to create the table and then delete it.

Comment: So renaming the table should help delete it..?

Comment: 100% . renaming will surely help.

Comment: I saw that the docs say "forces new resource" and thought this would do exactly that. I guess it's the process it uses to get there which failed.