# Adding a GSI to a DynamoDB table with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

It seems that modifying a dynamo table is [not allowed with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387833/10946893).

How would I go about adding a GSI to an existing table with terraform? I was previously doing it in python (with boto3 `update_table`), but now trying to do it in Terraform. I don't want to lose data nor to have to do it manually.

This is the error I keep getting:

```bash
Error: error creating DynamoDB Table: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists
```

And my code:

```
# Create a DynamoDB table with GSIs.
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
  name         = var.function_name
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "PK" # partition key
  range_key    = "SK" # sort key

  # Partition Key.
  attribute {
    name = "PK"
    type = "S"
  }

  # Sort Key (datetime in UTC).
  attribute {
    name = "SK"
    type = "S"
  }

  # Date (no time).
  attribute {
    name = "date"
    type = "S"
  }

  # Define a GSI.
  global_secondary_index {
    name            = "date-index"
    hash_key        = "date" # partition key
    range_key       = "SK"
    projection_type = "ALL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Modifying a table is allowed for values that can be updated. That is not a terraform thing; you just can change keys without recreating the table. You can on a GSI thought, just not main table or LSI.

Comment: @theherk you can add a GSI without recreating the table, but the table has to be managed by terraform first.

Comment: @MarkB: That is precisely what I intended; I was referencing the line that terraform doesn't allow updating tables. In summary, the issue was that it wasn't imported. Neither AWS nor terraform prevent addition of GSI's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import) your table into terraform. Only then you will be able to edit it using TF.