# How can I replace a DynamoDB table with an updated name attribute with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I have a DynamoDB table that is created with some Terraform that starts off like this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "mytable" {
  name         = "${var.environment_name}-mytable"
```

(let's say that var.environment name is set to `myenvironment`)

I need to use terraform to replace it with an empty version of the table, for which I am trying to use the `-replace` argument, like so:

```
terraform plan -replace=aws_dynamodb_table.mytable -out plan.bin
terraform apply plan.bin
```

The problem is that doing this generates a `ResourceInUseException`:

```
Error: creating Amazon DynamoDB Table (myenvironment-mytable): ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: myenvironment-mytable
```

This gives me a double-bind.

If I change the table name in the `-replace` argument to match the name in the error message (ie. to be prefixed with the environment name) then it doesn't find the table. Checking the name of the table with `terraform state show` and `terraform state list` confirms that indeed, terraform thinks the table name is not prefixed with the environment name, and it wants to operate on the table that way.

However, if I leave the table name alone (ie. don't prefix the environment name) then I get the error above - it says it can't replace it because it's in use. Sure enough, if I look in DynamoDB using the AWS console, the table exists with a name that is prefixed with the environment name.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387610/changing-hash-key-with-terraform-causes-table-already-exists-error) with an answer that suggests it maybe can't cope with being asked to replace a table that already exists and I need to either delete or rename it first, but I'd really prefer not to do that - I want to do a create_before_replace (I'm not there yet!) and surely the whole point of `-replace` is that the resource must already exist or you wouldn't be trying to replace it?

I don't know how to resolve this. How do I tell Terraform which table it is I'm trying to replace without having it either fail to find it or complain that it's already in use but named differently?

Comment: are you trying rename the dynamodb table name that already has items in it ?

Comment: No. I'm trying to wipe the contents of the table and restore it to a pristine (empty) state. It's potentially quite large, so I was hoping to do it by just telling Dynamo to recreate the table rather than by explicitly deleting everything in it, which might take a while.

Comment: I see , could you not just comment out the resource , do an apply and then uncomment it by reapplying the tf config? that will delete the table from my understanding

Comment: Yeah (or at least, something to that effect), I was trying to do it atomically. I don't think I actually need to though, so I probably will just destroy it and then create it again separately.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to answer the original question (how to get `-replace` to work with a non-empty DynamoDB table) and my suspicion is that it isn't possible, that Terraform will not do an atomic replace on an existing non-empty table. But I don't know that for sure.

What I have done is to do this non-atomically instead. This may be of use to some, and to others who want an answer to my original question, it may not be. But here's what I ended up doing.

```
terraform plan -destroy -target=aws_dynamodb_table.mytable -out plan.bin
terraform apply plan.bin
terraform plan -out plan.bin
terraform apply plan.bin
```

This deletes the original table (it looks like it's destroying everything, but it doesn't) and then creates it again from the original plan. Terraform spits out a nasty warning that you shouldn't really use -target (because it leaves your configuration in a state that isn't the same as your configuration files), but as long as you remember it's done that and don't forget to re-create it again, this seems fine to me.

I'm not accepting this answer because it doesn't answer the original question (it's a partial work-around) so if anyone does have an answer to the original question, I'm all ears!

EDIT: Oh, noticeably, the table name is the one in the resource declaration (ie. without the environment name prepended) not the one from the "name" attribute.